# VBS Run exe opens app many times instead of one

Tags: vbscript

I'm automating process of connection to remote PC which includes VPN+SSH+VNC and ssh stage automatization opens too much new windows instead of one expected.

Code:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run("""G:\Git\git-bash.exe""")
oShell.AppActivate "MINGW64:/"

Dim command
command = "ssh -A username@adress options~"
oShell.SendKeys command
```

Opens from 3 to 5 git-bash instances instead of 1.
Sending keys works as intended in 1 of this 3-5 window. How to prevent opening others?

Comment: Does `oShell.Run(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMSPEC% /C (start G:\Git\git-bash.exe)"))` help?  Might also try adding a `WScript.Sleep 3000` before calling AppActivate to give the OS time to launch git-bash.exe and its dependencies.  Hopefully, drive G: is a local drive.  If not, increase the Sleep time to give any anti-virus time to scan the process.

Comment: @leeharvey1 Thank you for the perfect detailed responce. "Sleep" did the thing. Please post this as an answer and i'll accept and rate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oShell.Run(oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%COMSPEC% /C (start G:\Git\git-bash.exe)"))` should help.

Might also try adding a `WScript.Sleep 3000` before calling `oShell.AppActivate` to give the OS time to launch **git-bash.exe** and its dependencies.

Hopefully, drive **G:** is a local drive. If not, increase the *Sleep* time to give any anti-virus time to scan the process.